# Automapper - How to map with dependency on current Session object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I am using Automapper within an ASP.Net MVC application to map DTO's to ViewModel objects.

in one of my mappings I need access to an object stored in the Session object.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
...
    SecurityToken token = SecurityTokenFactory.CreateSecurityToken(userNode);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Session[securityToken] = token;
...
}
```

In the constructor of my controller I set up the Automapper mapping.

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<UserReportDTO, UserDefinedReportModel>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.IsEditable, opt=>opt.ResolveUsing(src => this.IsEditable(src)));

 private bool IsEditable(UserReportDTO report)
 {
    if (this.GetCurrentUserToken().UserVisibilityLevel == VisibilityLevel.Root)
    {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
 }


 public JsonResult GetVisibleUserReports()
        {
            ...
            int ID = this.GetCurrentUserToken().UserId; //This works!
            var reports = Mapper.Map < UserReportDTO[], UserDefinedReportModel[] >(inputarray); //This doesn't work
            ...
         }
```

What happens is that the context.Session is null.

I'm guessing this is something to do with the way Automapper resolves the mapping - maybe a reference to one Context is set when the mapping is created, and then this Context no longer exists at mapping time?

How can I resolve the issue - is there a way to pass a parameter to a mapping operation?

My temporary workaround is to map all the other fields, and then manually loop through the mapped-collection, setting the field that requires the current context, but I'm loathe to keep this approach.

Answer (score 0):

A couple thoughts that might put you on the right track:

- Does it make any difference if you replace `ResolveUsing` with `MapFrom`? Both seem to accept a `Func<TSource, TMember>`, but perhaps there are subtle differences.
- Would it be possible to turn your `IsEditable` method into an `IValueResolver` then pass the required session data into the constructor using AutoMapper's `ConstructedBy()` feature? Here's the [relevant documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers). Scroll to the "Custom constructor methods" section.

Comment: I tried MapFrom first - but switching to ResolveUsing made no difference. I will try the IValueResolver approach - I hadn't tried this because it didn't look like it offered me anything different, but I hadn't seen the ConstructedBy feature which looks like I can direct to a factory function - thanks for the tip!